# Failing in basic travis.yml in PHP env

Tags: php, travis-ci

i'm newbie & trying to learn **travis** within my **PHP** development environment.

It's very "basic", i just trying a sample **.travis.yml** from official guide. But it always failing.

My repo is here https://github.com/rahmatawaludin/learn_travis and my travis build is here http://travis-ci.org/rahmatawaludin/learn-travis .

Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you followed the [PHPUnit manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html).

If you want to write a test for class `MyClass` (file MyClass.php), the corresponding tests would be in class `MyClassTest` (file MyClassTest.php).

Now if you want to run the test you'd call `phpunit` like that:

```
 phpunit MyClassTest
```

But you called `phpunit` with the filename, just remove the `.php` extension, then it should work.